# Wired router with wireless as internet source?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, wireless-router

I have a number of servers in my room, and I'd like to have a high-speed wired LAN within the room between my servers and my desktop and laptop. My internet access is provided by a cable modem connected to a wireless router, and I'd like it to stay that way (my Internet connection setup is at the other end of the house). Are there any routers (wireless or wired) out there that could provide a wired LAN in my room, but use a wireless connection as the Internet source? (the router in my room would be connected to my house's hotspot and use that as the Internet connection for the LAN in my room).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a router that you can run [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) on (The [Linksys WRT54GL](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?item=N82E16833124190) is a popular one) and use [Client Mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I looked through the supported devices list of DD-WRT and decided to get the [Linksys E2000](http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-Linksys-E2000-Advanced-Wireless-N-Router/dp/B003B20F54) (needed N support for faster Internet).

Answer (score 0):

Now obviously this is not the ideal configuration - but when I need to get LAN access to a location where wiring just isn't possible, I'll either use an Airport Express, or a PowerLine Ethernet Adapter.

For your particular situation, it'd likely be best to install a Wireless Airport Express, and enable the ethernet port to distribute in bridge mode.  (Definitely make sure it's not distributing it's on IP addresses by disabling DHCP - otherwise you'll have both dual NAT'ing and a potential IP conflict.)

Buy a switch as well, plug it into the Airport's ethernet port, and now you have 'Wired' connectivity on the other side of your space.